Why aren't coyotes hunted for meat?
I've heard that coyotes can be shot any time of year in Ontario because they are a nuisance animal, but coyotes aren't often hunted for meat.
Why aren't coyotes hunted for meat?

Resemble dogs; we like dogs
Meat doesn't taste good to most people
Too lean; not enough meat
Something else?

Eastern Ontario.

Hunting predators for meat isn't particularly common in many cultures (though all we know about your background is that you live somewhere with coyotes).  Hunting them for fur and trophies seems more common

Meat eaters (human and animal) commonly eat vegetarian animals.

https://phys.org/news/2017-12-carnivores-carnivore-carcasses-transmits-diseases.html for example

I would also worry about diseases given that coyotes are far from picky in their eating habits.

I think that "we like dogs" does not refer to them as cooked, and on a plate? ;) That was the first meaning I got when I first read - because of the context of "hunt for meat"...

Coyotes are largely scavengers, so their meat is both very gamey and doesn't taste good and could be ridden with parasites like trichinella. It's much safer to both hunt and eat herbivores, so that's why we usually go after deer or rabbit than coyotes or bears.

People hunt fairly few carnivores for food.
Exceptions:  Inuit hunt seals and polar bear.
Many first nations hunt black bear, but generally only in late sumemr fall when they have had a mostly vegetarian summer.  You do not want to eat bear meat after a few weeks of it stuffing itself on salmon.
No one hunts wolf or cougar for meat that I know of.
In the bird world, waterfowl that primarily eat fish are don't taste great either.
An acquaintance of mine had a pig that he was raising for fall slaughter.  He was a whitefish fisher on Lake Winnipeg.  Fed the offal to the pig.  His plan was to feed the pig on grain for 6-8 weeks before slaughtering it in November.
The pig had a misadventure when it tried to eat a live extension cord.  My friend made the best of a bad situation and butchered the pig immediately and cured the meet into hams and bacon.
Cooking it smelled wonderful.  Tasted like something between tuna and sardines.

If you want all year huntable meat:

Rabbit. (probably easier to learn to snare)
Squirrel.  (Snare.  Or Use a pellet gun.  Even a .22 is too much, unless you "bark" the squirrel by shooting the twig under him)
Beaver.  (Lots of accounts of this in the fur trade)
Porcupine.  (Can have overtones of turpentine if it's been eating pine bark.

